# How can I calculate cut-off points from a normal distribution?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, sampling, expected-value, skewness

I'm trying to calculate the upper percentage points for the 0.99 percentile for samples drawn from a normal distribution, with a sample size of 500. How can I calculate the expected values for skewness, kurtosis, studentized range, which would be expected for a drawing of 500 values?

Comment: When you say "calculate" do you want mathematical formulae, or a way of getting a numerical approximation? (And is this homework?)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student_t

Comment: no this is no homework :P. yes a formula would be nice, I'm somehow unsure how to integrate the sample size here. The objective is to know the approximative numerical value which can be expected, when 500 values are drawn..

Comment: This question appears to contradict itself: are you drawing samples from a normal distribution or a Student t distribution?  Which one?  (PS: You're right: this site is a better choice for the question than the *Mathematica* site.  Once you get your question straightened out here, if you need specific help with MMA in coding a solution you will know precisely what to ask over there as a follow-up.)

Comment: I could do an Confidence interval but i'm somehow missing the standard deviation which would be needed to derive theorethically? I assume it to be close to zero for 500 values for the skewness, respectively to 3 for the kurtosis..?

Comment: OK, you're drawing 500 values (presumably independently) from a Student t distribution.  But what, exactly, are you trying to estimate?  You mention "upper percentage points" and a 99th percentile.  These have nothing to do with expected values of skewness, kurtosis, or studentized range mentioned in the second sentence.  These requests just don't make sense: right now, they're just an unrelated jumble of statistical terms.  Could you perhaps identify *one single thing* you are attempting to accomplish and edit the question to focus on that?

Comment: yes unfortunately that's the problem I have too. It is from a text where there is an empirical distribution for 250 values, where skewness is 0.60, compared to the theoretical one. then they say: "0.6 for skewness exceed the value of the 0.99 fractile of the repsective distribution expexted under normality." With a following table: Upper percentage points: samples of 250 drawn from a normal population: 0.99 --> skewness 0.129. I now try to compute these 0.129..? resp. adapt to 500 values..

Comment: My guess is they show the (simulated) skewness and kurtosis of the distribution of the sample 95th and 99th percentiles (with normal data, n=250).  This is (depending on your sample quantile estimator) the same as the 248th order statistic.  This paper http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167715207002143 gives an analytic formula for the k-th moment of the r-th order statistic of a sample of normal data of size n, which technically answers your question (I think).  But it looks complex (Lauricella function of type A?); maybe better off simulating.

Comment: thx a lot i will try to follow the paper. what we tried to do underneath is simulate those percentiles but ended up with much higher values for the percentiles..

Answer (score 3):

You can always simulate this kind of thing first, e.g. in R

```
set.seed(1)
samat <- matrix(rnorm(1000000), ncol=500)
means <- rowMeans(samat)
varis <- rowMeans((samat-means)^2)
skews <- rowMeans((samat-means)^3) / varis^(3/2)
kurts <- rowMeans((samat-means)^4) / varis^2  -  3
```

and find the quantiles

```
> quantile(means, probs=c(0.01, 0.5, 0.99) )
          1%          50%          99% 
-0.096977914 -0.001302285  0.109797211 
>
> quantile(varis, probs=c(0.01, 0.5, 0.99) )
       1%       50%       99% 
0.8494985 0.9970259 1.1495887 
>
> quantile(skews, probs=c(0.01, 0.5, 0.99) )
          1%          50%          99% 
-0.257665499 -0.002052328  0.260948808 
>
> quantile(kurts, probs=c(0.01, 0.5, 0.99) )
        1%        50%        99% 
-0.4286435 -0.0320487  0.5399296
```

and while it is clear that you can probably only treat the first couple of decimal places as useful, it also shows that skewness of 0.60 would be extremely high.  It also suggests that the "skewness 0.129" you quote is rather low for the 99th percentile; I make it nearer 0.35 or 0.36 for a sample of 250 and about 0.26 for a sample of 500.